# Is there a way to disable fading that a viewPager has scroll to edges?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Scrollable views such as the ListView have a fade blue effect  along the edges where there is no content and scroll to the end. How can I close the effect?

at listview i can use :

```
 setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
 android:fadingEdge="none"
 android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
```

but at the viewPager not useful,can give me some advice

Answer (score 88):

**I have a solution:**

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Now everything is OK. I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/3RcB6xgNAg8).

Answer (score 3):

```
 viewPager2.getChildAt(0)?.overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
```

Answer (score 2):

Java:

```
((RecyclerView)viewPager.getChildAt(0)).setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

Answer (score -2):

pengwang's answer is good,but it is above android 10.If we use lower version.Try this.

```
 try{
    Method method = context.getClass().getMethod("setOverScrollMode",int.class);
    Field field = context.getClass().getField("OVER_SCROLL_NEVER");
    if(method!=null && field!=null){
        method.invoke(viewpager,field.getInt(View.class));
    }
}
catch(Exception e){

}
```